# Unable to download AWS CodeDeploy Agent Install file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to download AWS Codedeploy Agent file in my Amazon Linux. I followed instructions as mentioned in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-run-agent.html, for Amazon Linux, have created appropriate instance profile, service role etc. Everything is latest (Amazon Linux, CLI Packages, it is a brand new instance and I have tried this with at least 3 more brand new instances with same result). All instances have full outbound internet access.

But following statement for downloading install from S3 always fails,

`aws s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/install . --region us-east-1`

With Error,
A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out the problem, According to Codedeploy documentation for IAM Instance profile

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-iam-instance-profile.html

following permissions needs to be given to your IAM instance profile.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I limited the resource to my code bucket since I don't want my instances to access other buckets directly. But turns out I also need to give additional permission for aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/* s3 resource for being able to download the agent. This is not very clear in the document for setting up IAM instance profile for Codedeploy.

Comment: You can still get this error if the CLI user credentials lack the necessary permissions.

Comment: It made more sense for me to attach another managed policy to the IAM user I am using for code deployment - policy name "AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess"

Answer (score 2):

More restrictive policy that works:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-us-west-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-us-west-2/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ap-south-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-2/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-2/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-eu-central-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-eu-west-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-sa-east-1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```